# No operator "<<" matches but ">>" works

Tags: c++, file-io, stream

I have an issue in C++ getting the "No operator "<<" matches these operands" error(at fout << dog). This is how my code looks like:

```
int FileRepository::addDog(const Dog& dog)
{
    if (this->findDog(dog.getName()) != -1)
        return -1; 
    std::ofstream fout;
    fout.open(this->fileName.c_str(), std::ios_base::app);
    fout << dog;
    fout.close();
    return 0;
}
```

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& outputStream, Dog& dog)
{
    outputStream << dog.name << ", " << dog.breed << ", " << dog.birthDate << ", " << dog.numberOfShots << ", " << dog.photo << ", " << '\n';
    return outputStream;
}
```

Also I have imported the specific headers and libraries and the ">>" operator works.

Here it works:

```
void FileRepository::writeVectorToFile(std::vector<Dog> vectorOfDogs)
{
    ofstream fout(this->fileName.c_str());
    for (Dog dog : vectorOfDogs)
        fout << dog;
    fout.close();
}
```

Comment: btw you should have used a `const Dog&` in the range based loop too, ie `for (const Dog& dog : vectorOfDogs)` because currently you are making unnecessary copies of the dogs in the vector. (then you would get the same error)

Comment: Questions like this should contain a [mcve].

Comment: The vector is unnecessarily copied too

Answer (score 6):

In the operator the second parameter is not a constant reference

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& outputStream, Dog& dog)
{
    outputStream << dog.name << ", " << dog.breed << ", " << dog.birthDate << ", " << dog.numberOfShots << ", " << dog.photo << ", " << '\n';
    return outputStream;
}
```

while in the member function there is used a constant reference to object.

```
int FileRepository::addDog(const Dog& dog)
```

Declare the operator like

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& outputStream, const Dog& dog)
{
    outputStream << dog.name << ", " << dog.breed << ", " << dog.birthDate << ", " << dog.numberOfShots << ", " << dog.photo << ", " << '\n';
    return outputStream;
}
```